# Activate or DeActivate requirement status of field based on another field

Tags: forms

I want to alter a form in my drupal 7 project.
I want to **activate or deactivate** **requirement status** of a field **programmatically** based on another field value.

if field value is male , military status field must be **required** but if it is female, military status is not required and also it must be **hide**.

Please guide me in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is make the military field not required. Then add your own validate function to the form with:

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_function_name';
```

Then in your function you can do a check e.g.

```
function my_function_name*$form, &$form_state){
  if($form_state['values']['my_gender_field'] == 'male' && empty($form_state['values']['my_military_field'])){
     form_set_error('my_military_field', 'Military field is required');
  }
}
```

Or you could try using #states from the form API which has a 'required' option:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#states

Comment: it is good but I want to call some codes via ajax when a dropdown menu value is changed. imagine that I want to delete a form element in ajax called function. I have added ['#ajax'] and callbacks to form inside module_form_alter , but I don't know how can I remove a form element from or add new from element to form object inside ajax_called_function. can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

In order to test a solution to your needs I've used a form alter for the *article*.
I've added few comments in the code, I hope they will be enough.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_article_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['gender'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Gender'),
    '#options' => [
      '_none' => t('Please select gender'),
      'm' => t('Male'),
      'f' => t('Female'),
    ],
    '#default_value' => '_none',
    // Ajax info:
    '#ajax' => [
      // This method returns an array of ajax commands or a form element already prepared.
      'callback' => 'my_module_ajax_responder',
      // This will tell wich dom id will be replaced with the response.data
      'wrapper' => 'military_status_dom_id',
      // pretty obiouvs
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ],
  ];

  // Required property has been set to FALSE as default because no gender has been selected yet
  $required = FALSE;
  // this if will be ignored on page load, it means no submit has been done yet.
  if (!empty($form_state['triggering_element']) && $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'] === 'gender') {
    // but if user selects a gender, there will be an ajax submit and this will change 
    // the required property of the military_status texfield element that is going to be
    // rebuilt
    $required = $form_state['triggering_element']['#value'] === 'm';
  }
  // now the actual military_status texfield element.
  $form['military_status'] = [
    '#prefix' => '<div id="military_status_dom_id">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Military status'),
    '#required' => $required,
  ];
}

/**
 * Ajax responder.
 */
function my_module_ajax_responder($form, &$form_state) {
  // after submit and form rebuild, ajax knows that it has to call this method
  // to recover a response data.
  // This data will be used to be a replacement (in this case) for the wrapper 
  // specified in the $form['gender'] element.
  return $form['military_status'];
}
```

Here some more explatanation:

- Form will be built and then altered, therefore your alter function will be called
- there is an *if* to check if this is a phase of build during the page load or during the ajax submit
- in this case we tell to drupal that as soon as a user select a gender it has to submit their choice and let us check it, checnge the required property of the military_status field and finally call the "callback" function to retrieve the modified element that will be replaced