# How to find operation type in validating form?

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a custom validate function for **specific node form**.

But validate rules are **different** between edit a current node or add a new node modes.

Now, I want to know, is there any way that we understand whether we are in **edit mode or create mode** in form_validate function ?

Comment: In which version you are trying to adding your custom form... D7 or D8?

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to write drupal version . D7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new node will not have a node ID.

So you can check the form values or the original form for that to determine whether it is a new node or not.

For example:

```
if (empty($form_state['values']['nid'])) {
  // This is a new node.
}
else {
  // This is an existing node.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot rooby. I used your suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Rooby solution is good, but I usually check the presence of "nid" property in $form['#node']

```
function my_module_form_validate_func(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (!isset($form['#node']->nid)) {
    //new node
  }
  else {
    //existing node
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, there are at least 4 ways I can think of to check in various places in $form and $form_state. All valid.

Comment: Thanks for you attention. I have some other questions in different issues in drupal 7. if you can please visit https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264230/activate-or-deactivate-requirement-status-of-field-based-on-another-field